# Jekyll - Style a part of code in highlight code block

Tags: jekyll, liquid, pygments

I use pygments to highlight code.

And I want to add some specify style to a part of code in highlight block.

For example, I want to change "private String" color to red.

```
{% highlight java %}
public class A {
    <span color="red">private String</span> xx;
}
{% endhighlight %}
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

A Name token is transformed by Pygments to :

```
<span class="n">Private</span>
<span class="n">String</span>
<span class="n">name</span>

or 

<span class="o">(</span>
<span class="n">String</span>
<span class="n">name</span>
<span class="o">){</span>
```

Styling **.n** class can be done in your highlight.css (or maybe .scss) with :

```
.highlight .n{ color: red; }
```

But you will not target the **Private String** specific token.
If you want to do so, you will have to write you own Pygments lexer